# installing aws_s3 to a postgres db hosted in an aws ec2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I would like to fetch the contents of a postgres db into an s3 bucket. To do this, I need to install the aws_s3 and aws_commons extensions in the database. However, when I follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html), I get this error:

```
some_postgress_db=# CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;


ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/aws_s3.control": No such file or directory

The folder exists but the file aws_s3.control is not in the directory
```

Comment: Those instructions are specifically for RDS, which you apparently are not using.  There is [clone](https://github.com/chimpler/postgres-aws-s3) which says it works on the community version of PostgrreSQL.